# Using volley and Glide to download, display and cache images

Tags: android, caching, android-volley, android-glide

I can't wrap my head around this, probably because of lack of my experience. I have images on server, I get their path in JSON along with description and a name. I am getting all of that data with Volley.

```
private static final String TAG = "StoreActivity";
private RecyclerView shopsRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
private ArrayList<Store> stores;
private StoreAdapter storeAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_store);

    shopsRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.shopsRecyclerView);
    shopsRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    shopsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    stores = new ArrayList<>();
    storeAdapter = new StoreAdapter(getApplicationContext(), stores);
    shopsRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new StoreAdapter.RecyclerTouchListener(getApplicationContext(), shopsRecyclerView, new StoreAdapter.ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position) {
            Intent i = new Intent(StoreActivity.this, ProductsActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

        }
    }));
    fetchStores();
}

private void fetchStores() {
    JsonObjectRequest fetchAllStores = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, API.GET_STORES, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Fetch Stores: " + response);
            showStores(response);
            shopsRecyclerView.setAdapter(storeAdapter);
            storeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Fetch Stores Error: " + error.getMessage());
        }
    });
    ApplicationController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(fetchAllStores);
}

private void showStores(JSONObject response) {
    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("images");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            Store store = new Store();
            store.setId(jsonObject.getString("id"));
            store.setImage_url(jsonObject.getString("url"));
            store.setTitle(jsonObject.getString("name"));
            stores.add(store);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Show Stores: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Then I put that path/url I got from Volley in Glide and load all of the images in RecyclerView.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(StoreViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    Store store = stores.get(position);
    holder.tvDescription.setText(store.getTitle());
    Glide.with(context)
            .load(store.getImage_url())
            .placeholder(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_upload_you_tube)
            .error(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_error)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
            .into(holder.ivImage);

}
```

Next time I turn on the same activity, the request is sent again and images are downloaded again? Or are they previously cached somehow and they are loaded from cache?
When I turn off internet and turn on the same activity, nothing happens, because the volley request can't be sent, and the images I thought were cached aren't shown. 
What would be the best approach for my problem? Basically, I need to get the images's path from server and place them in my recyclerview but I also want them to be cached so they are not downloaded every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to suggest you to use Glide lib, very simple and caches images for your app, I have tried it myself. You can also add signature to the url so that next time it is updated it has to change.

[Glide Url](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

Below is code Snippet :

```
dependencies {
        // glide
        compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
  }

String imgUrl = "http://imageurl";

ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);


    Glide.with(mContext).load(imgUrl)
                .thumbnail(0.5f)
                .crossFade()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(imageView);
```

Hope this Helps.

Comment: Hey, I have already used Glide, but I have to somehow get the images from server and that is why I use volley. The rest is in my question. :)

Comment: you want to fetch images? if yes then you  have to save images to server, then  you have to fetch the links of the images . you may use Retrofit instead of volley.

Comment: Darpan, I have already done all of that. What I want to know is if the images fetched by volley and then shown in the imageviews with Glide are cached? Next time when I run the app, will Glide load the cached images or wait for volley to fetch them again? I would also like to know what are the best practices for this.

Comment: @jlively my friend i have told you that Glide caches the image.
Glide uses various disk caching startegies and you ca use according to your need
//This are various Types.
    DiskCacheStrategy.NONE caches nothing

    DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE caches only the original full-resolution image.

    DiskCacheStrategy.RESULT caches only the final image, after reducing the resolution.

    DiskCacheStrategy.ALL caches all versions of the image

And yes your image is cached using Glide.

This is all i know Bro. 
Hope it Helps :)